# How to make JavaScript form validation update while user types

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I have a form validation script that warns the user of problems with their form when they submit. I was wondering how to remove the warnings while the user types and fixes their mistake. For example, if you submit an empty field, the text "Can't be blank" appears, I want that text to disappear as soon as the user starts typing in the input field, thus making the field not blank anymore. Any help is appreciated and goes a long way. Thank you!

HTML

```
                <!-- Individual Form -->
                <form id="individual" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateStudentSignUpForm()" autocomplete="off">

                    <!-- Individual First Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="firstid" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="first" name="first" type="text" placeholder="First name" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Individual Last Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="lastid" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="last" name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last name" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Individual Email -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="email1id" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control email" id="email1" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Individual Password -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="password1id" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="password1" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Individual's Birthday -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Birthday</label>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <!-- Month -->
                            <select id="month1" name="month" onChange="changeDate1(this.options[selectedIndex].value);" class="form-control month-space">
                                <option value="na">Month</option>
                                <option value="1">January</option>
                                <option value="2">February</option>
                                <option value="3">March</option>
                                <option value="4">April</option>
                                <option value="5">May</option>
                                <option value="6">June</option>
                                <option value="7">July</option>
                                <option value="8">August</option>
                                <option value="9">September</option>
                                <option value="10">October</option>
                                <option value="11">November</option>
                                <option value="12">December</option>
                            </select>

                            <!-- Day -->
                            <select name="day" id="day1" class="form-control day-space">
                                <option value="na">Day</option>
                            </select>

                            <!-- Year -->
                            <select name="year" id="year1" class="form-control year-space">
                                <option value="na">Year</option>
                            </select>

                            <span id="date1id" class="text-warning"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn blue-button">Confirm</button>

                </form>

                <!-- Parent Form -->
                <form id="parent" class="hidden" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateStudentSignUpForm()" autocomplete="off">

                    <!-- Parent's First Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="parent-firstid" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="parent-first" name="parent-first" type="text" placeholder="Parent's first name" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Parent's Last Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="parent-lastid" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="parent-last" name="parent-last" type="text" placeholder="Parent's last name" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Parent Email -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="email2id" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email2" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Parent Password -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="password2id" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="password2" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Child's First Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span id="child-firstid" class="text-warning"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" id="child-first" name="child-first" type="text" placeholder="Child's first name" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Child's Birthday -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Child's birthday</label>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <!-- Month -->
                            <select id="month2" name="month" onChange="changeDate2(this.options[selectedIndex].value);" class="form-control month-space">
                                <option value="na">Month</option>
                                <option value="1">January</option>
                                <option value="2">February</option>
                                <option value="3">March</option>
                                <option value="4">April</option>
                                <option value="5">May</option>
                                <option value="6">June</option>
                                <option value="7">July</option>
                                <option value="8">August</option>
                                <option value="9">September</option>
                                <option value="10">October</option>
                                <option value="11">November</option>
                                <option value="12">December</option>
                            </select>

                            <!-- Day -->
                            <select name="day" id="day2" class="form-control day-space">
                                <option value="na">Day</option>
                            </select>

                            <!-- Year -->
                            <select name="year" id="year2" class="form-control year-space">
                                <option value="na">Year</option>
                            </select>

                            <span id="date2id" class="text-warning"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn blue-button">Confirm</button>
                </form>

                <p class="text-center" id="small">By signing up you agree to our
                    <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> and
                    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function validateStudentSignUpForm() {
    var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("last").value;
    var email1 = document.getElementById("email1").value;
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    var parentFirst = document.getElementById("parent-first").value;
    var parentLast = document.getElementById("parent-last").value;
    var childFirst = document.getElementById("child-first").value;
    var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
    var month1 = document.getElementById("month1").value;
    var day1 = document.getElementById("day1").value;
    var year1 = document.getElementById("year1").value;
    var month2 = document.getElementById("month2").value;
    var day2 = document.getElementById("day2").value;
    var year2 = document.getElementById("year2").value;
    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var nameFilter = /^([^0-9]*)$/;

    // First name can't be blank
    if (first == "") {
        document.getElementById("first").className = document.getElementById("first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("firstid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // First name can't be a number
    else if (!nameFilter.test(first)) {
        document.getElementById("first").className = document.getElementById("first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("firstid").innerHTML = "Can't have numbers";
    }

    // First name can't be longer than 50 characters
    else if (first.length > 50) {
        document.getElementById("first").className = document.getElementById("first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("firstid").innerHTML = "Name is too long";
    }

    // Last name can't be blank
    if (last == "") {
        document.getElementById("last").className = document.getElementById("last").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("lastid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Last name can't be a number
    else if (!nameFilter.test(last)) {
        document.getElementById("last").className = document.getElementById("last").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("lastid").innerHTML = "Can't have numbers";
    }

    // Last name can't be longer than 50 characters
    else if (last.length > 50) {
        document.getElementById("last").className = document.getElementById("last").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("lastid").innerHTML = "Name is too long";
    }

    // Email can't be blank
    if (email1 == "") {
        document.getElementById("email1").className = document.getElementById("email1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("email1id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Email test
    else if (!emailFilter.test(email1)) {
        document.getElementById("email1").className = document.getElementById("email1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("email1id").innerHTML = "Use a proper email format";
    }

    // Password can't be blank
    if (password1 == "") {
        document.getElementById("password1").className = document.getElementById("password1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("password1id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Password has to be 6 characters
    else if (password1.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById("password1").className = document.getElementById("password1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("password1id").innerHTML = "Password must be 6 characters long";
    }

    // Password can't be longer than 100 characters
    else if (password1.length > 100) {
        document.getElementById("password1").className = document.getElementById("password1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("password1id").innerHTML = "Password must be less than 100 characters long";
    }

    // Parent first can't be blank
    if (parentFirst == "") {
        document.getElementById("parent-first").className = document.getElementById("parent-first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("parent-firstid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Parent first can't be a number
    else if (!nameFilter.test(parentFirst)) {
        document.getElementById("parent-first").className = document.getElementById("parent-first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("parent-firstid").innerHTML = "Can't have numbers";
    }

    // Parent first can't be longer than 50 characters
    else if (parentFirst.length > 50) {
        document.getElementById("parent-first").className = document.getElementById("parent-first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("parent-firstid").innerHTML = "Name is too long";
    }

    // Parent last can't be blank
    if (parentLast == "") {
        document.getElementById("parent-last").className = document.getElementById("parent-last").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("parent-lastid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Parent last can't be a number
    else if (!nameFilter.test(parentLast)) {
        document.getElementById("parent-last").className = document.getElementById("parent-last").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("parent-lastid").innerHTML = "Can't have numbers";
    }

    // Parent last can't be longer than 50 characters
    else if (parentLast.length > 50) {
        document.getElementById("parent-last").className = document.getElementById("parent-last").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("parent-lastid").innerHTML = "Name is too long";
    }

    // Child first can't be blank
    if (childFirst == "") {
        document.getElementById("child-first").className = document.getElementById("child-first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("child-firstid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Child first can't be a number
    else if (!nameFilter.test(childFirst)) {
        document.getElementById("child-first").className = document.getElementById("child-first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("child-firstid").innerHTML = "Can't have numbers";
    }

    // Child first can't be longer than 50 characters
    else if (childFirst.length > 50) {
        document.getElementById("child-first").className = document.getElementById("child-first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("child-firstid").innerHTML = "Name is too long";
    }

    // Email can't be blank
    if (email2 == "") {
        document.getElementById("email2").className = document.getElementById("email2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("email2id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Email2 test
    else if (!emailFilter.test(email2)) {
        document.getElementById("email2").className = document.getElementById("email2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("email2id").innerHTML = "Use a proper email format";
    }

    // Password can't be blank
    if (password2 == "") {
        document.getElementById("password2").className = document.getElementById("password2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("password2id").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
    }

    // Password has to be 6 characters
    else if (password2.length < 6) {
        document.getElementById("password2").className = document.getElementById("password2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("password2id").innerHTML = "Password must be 6 characters long";
    }

    // Password can't be longer than 100 characters
    else if (password2.length > 100) {
        document.getElementById("password2").className = document.getElementById("password2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("password2id").innerHTML = "Password must be less than 100 characters long";
    }

    // Month1 can't be default
    if (month1 === "na") {
        document.getElementById("month1").className = document.getElementById("month1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("date1id").innerHTML = "Choose a valid date";
    }

    // Day1 can't be default
    if (day1 === "na") {
        document.getElementById("day1").className = document.getElementById("day1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("date1id").innerHTML = "Choose a valid date";
    }

    // Month1 can't be default
    if (year1 === "na") {
        document.getElementById("year1").className = document.getElementById("year1").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("date1id").innerHTML = "Choose a valid date";
    }

    // Month2 can't be default
    if (month2 === "na") {
        document.getElementById("month2").className = document.getElementById("month2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("date2id").innerHTML = "Choose a valid date";
    }

    // Day2 can't be default
    if (day2 === "na") {
        document.getElementById("day2").className = document.getElementById("day2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("date2id").innerHTML = "Choose a valid date";
    }

    // Year2 can't be default
    if (year2 === "na") {
        document.getElementById("year2").className = document.getElementById("year2").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("date2id").innerHTML = "Choose a valid date";
    }

    return false;
}


.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onfocus` event to your input fields which will remove validation warning messages

Comment: I added onfocus="return validateStudentSignUpForm". However, that didn't work. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: You don't need to call validation function when the input is onfocus. Just clear validation message. Here is quick example based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qoz55to0/ Click on input.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to what you mean. Could you provide me an example of onfocus in action

Comment: Upd in previous comment. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You could approach that by doing something like this:

- Listen to onfocus on the input.
- Keep a variable that says if the alert was showed (true/false)
- Handle the onfocus by asking if that variable is true, if It is, just removes it from de DOM, if not, do nothing.

Comment: Could I have an example of a variable saying if an alert was shown

Comment: You could have a variable named "isMessageOpen" which has a value of false by default and whenever in your code you show up that message you also update that variable to true. Finally, you change the variable to false when the user closes the message (click event).

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest doing these validations with separate functions like this. Using jQuery would look something like this:

```
var isFirstNameValid = false;
var isLastNameValid = false;
var isPasswordValid = false;

$("#first").change(function(){
    if(this.value.length < 1){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
        $("#firstid").html("Can't be blank");
        isFirstNameValid = false;
    }
    else{
        $("#firstid").html("");
        $(this).css("border","1px solid black");
        isFirstNameValid = true;
    }
});

//here is another example you can use to check your validation:

$("#password1").focusout(function(){
    if(this.value.length < 6){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
        $("#password1id").html("must be longer than 6 char");
        isPasswordValid = false;
    }
    else if(this.value.length > 100){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
        $("#password1id").html("must be less than 100 char");
        isPasswordValid = false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).css("border","1px solid black");
         $("#password1id").html("");
         isPasswordValid = true;
    }

});

//or you can use this example to check your validation on every input you 
// make in the field:

$("#last").on("input", function(){
   if(this.value.length < 1){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
        $("#lastid").html("Can't be blank");
        isLastNameValid = false;
    }
    else if(this.value.length > 50){
        $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
        $("#lastid").html("must be less than 50 char");
        isLastNameValid = false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).css("border","1px solid black");
        $("#lastid").html("");
        isLastNameValid = true;           
    }

});


function validateStudentSignUpForm() {
// check if your validations are true
if(isFirstNameValid == true && isLastNameValid == true && 
isPasswordValid  ==  true){

var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
var last = document.getElementById("last").value;
var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
// any futre logic or code here
// you dont need the validations here in this funcion anymore

}}
```

to use jQuery you just need to write this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

before the the javascript in your HTML file.

OR

another solution without using jQuery might be something like this:

```
var firstName = document.getElementById('first');
var firstNameDisplay = document.getElementById('firstid');

firstName.addEventListener("oninput", function(){
      firstNameDisplay.innerHTML = "";
});
```

Everytime you start typing in the input field it will clear the message "Can't be blank". You will have to do this for all your input fields.
Read up on this it might help you.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Comment: if using jQuery `$(selector).on('input',...)` will work best for as you type validation

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how to remove the warnings while the user types and fixes their mistake

You need to perform same validation on each input event. Try out below changes in your code:

Change 1: Additional attribute `oninput` to the `form` tag

```
 <form id="individual" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateStudentSignUpForm()" oninput="return validateStudentSignUpForm()" autocomplete="off">
```

Change 2: You need to reset error messages.

```
document.getElementById("firstid").innerHTML = ""; /* reset, so on for the rest */
if (first == "") {
        document.getElementById("first").className = document.getElementById("first").className + " error";
        document.getElementById("firstid").innerHTML = "Can't be blank";
}
```